# using python 2.7 for windows executing an sh file

Tags: python, windows, shell

Windows 10.1 installed
python 2.7 installed

I have an application package that has a file named install.sh and the read me states to run the install.sh file.  I have tried numerous times to execute the .sh file without success.  I get a name error and that install is not defined.  What is the proper syntax to execute the .sh file as directed in my read me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a Bash shell installed to run `.sh` files. Easy options include [Git Bash](http://git-scm.com) and [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: Ok I have Cygwin and I have no idea what the syntax is to install an .sh file.  Can you please assist?

Comment: Change to the directory where the file is using the `cd` command. Then, run the file by typing `./install.sh` and it should work.